# Are [object Null] & [object Undefined] yet to be implemented?

Tags: javascript, null, undefined, specifications, ecmascript-5

While reading MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString), I came across

> Starting in JavaScript 1.8.5 toString() called on null returns [object
>   Null], and undefined returns [object Undefined], as defined in the 5th
>   Edition of ECMAScript and a subsequent Errata. See Using toString to
>   detect object type.

I tried `Object(null).toString()` & `Object(undefined).toString()`

and both returned  `"[object Object]"`

As per the [specification](http://es5.github.io/#x8), primitive types in JS are Undefined, Null, Boolean, Number, or String.

So would it be correct to assume that, at the moment, all the browsers are yet to implement:

`[object Undefined]` & `[object Null]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the internal [[Class]], you need to set the value as the `this` value of `Object.prototype.toString()`, so:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(null);      // [object Null]
Object.prototype.toString.call(undefined); // [object Undefined]
```

---

This is defined in ECMAScript 5 as follows:

> **8.6.2 Object Internal Properties and Methods**
>
> The value of the `[[Class]]` internal property is defined by this specification for every kind of built-in object. The value of the `[[Class]]` internal property of a host object may be any String value except one of `"Arguments", "Array", "Boolean", "Date", "Error", "Function", "JSON", "Math", "Number", "Object", "RegExp", and "String"`. The value of a [[Class]] internal property is used internally to distinguish different kinds of objects. **Note that this specification does not provide any means for a program to access that value except through `Object.prototype.toString`** (see 15.2.4.2).

Comment: Ohh my bad, before jumping into conclusions. Thanks.